# Angular2: Proper method to get an object by its unique Id from an array of objects?

Tags: angular, mean-stack

I have two arrays: `categories` and `articles`.

Here's what the arrays look like:

```
categories = [{id: 1, name: 'Gadgets'}, {id: 2, name: 'Artificial Intelligence'}, {id: 3, name: 'Opinions'}];   
articles = [{id: 1, categoryId: 3, title: 'Title 1', body: 'Body Text 1'}, {id: 2, categoryId: 1, title: 'Title 2', body: 'Body Text 2'}, {id: 3, categoryId: 1, title: 'Title 3', body: 'Body Text 3'}];
```

In the following news feed, the `categoryId` needs to be replaced by `category.name`. How would I get the required object from the array so I can access its name property - without having to loop through the `categories` array in the view?

I want to do something like `{{category(article.categoryId).name}}` in the template but it's not correct syntax.

[image]

**`Template:`**

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    <h4>{{article.title }}</h4> 
    <p>{{article.body }}</p> 
    <div class="tag tag-default">
        CategoryId: {{article.categoryId}} <!-- Need category.name -->
    </div>
   <div class="tag tag-success">
         Published: {{article.date_publish | date:'medium'}}
    </div>
    <div class="tag tag-info">
         Created: {{article.date_created  | date:'medium'}}
    </div>
</div>
```

**`ArticlesComponent`**

```
articles: Article[];
categories: Category[];

constructor(
  private _articleService: ArticleService,
  private _categoryService: CategoryService,
) {}

ngOnInit()
{
  this._articleService.getArticles().subscribe(articles => {this.articles = articles});
  this._categoryService.getCategories().subscribe(categories => {this.categories = categories});
}
```

Comment: is my solution working in your case ???  vivek

Answer (score 1):

you can call a function in your html for extracting category name

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    <h4>{{article.title }}</h4> 
    <p>{{article.body }}</p> 
    <div class="tag tag-default">
        CategoryId: {{categoryname(article.categoryId)}} <!-- Need category.name -->
    </div>
   <div class="tag tag-success">
         Published: {{article.date_publish | date:'medium'}}
    </div>
    <div class="tag tag-info">
         Created: {{article.date_created  | date:'medium'}}
    </div>
</div>
```

and in your component you can search for it in this.categories

```
    articles: Article[];
    categories: Category[];

    constructor(
      private _articleService: ArticleService,
      private _categoryService: CategoryService,
    ) {}

    ngOnInit()
    {
      this._articleService.getArticles().subscribe(articles => {this.articles = articles});
      this._categoryService.getCategories().subscribe(categories => {this.categories = categories});
    }

  categoryname(id: string){
      console.log(id);
      return this.categories[id];// add your code here if your array syntax is different, you can use lodash also
   }
```

and i think you can also use `{{categories[article.categoryId]}}` if your array is simple and put html part in `*ngIf` to prevent from undefined erros